# Trouble setting up Realm for ReactNative: `rnpm link realm` stalls without further info or output

Tags: ios, node.js, npm, react-native, realm

I am trying to setup [Realm](http://www.realm.io) for a React Native project, but the installation doesn't work. It fails on calling `rnpm link realm` where just nothing happens.

Here are the steps I took (closely followed [Realm's getting started for RN](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/)):

1. `npm install -g rnpm` // I needed to install `rnpm` as it wasn't installed before
2. `react-native init MyDebts`
3. `npm install --save realm`
4. `rnpm link realm`

I am using node v5.0.0.

Note that I also added some more dependencies to my `package.json`:
[image]

When calling `rnpm link realm` in the directory of the project, the process stalls without any output or further information:
[image]

Note that I tried the following trouble-shooting actions without success:

1. `watchman watch-del-all`
2. `rm -rf node_modules` (and rerunning `npm install`)
3. *deep* clean in Xcode (cmd+alt+shift+k)

The results on calling `rnpm link realm` remains the same (namely nothing :)).

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working. What version of rnpm are you using?

Comment: It's version `1.6.0`

Comment: You also have the option of adding Realm to your project manually without rnpm. To do this drag the project at `node_modules/realm/react-native/ios/RealmReact.xcodeproj` into your project, and add `libRealmReact.a` to the `Link Binary with Libraries` phase for your app.

Comment: hmm.. weird! your comment made just made me try it again and now it worked! tried it several times this morning (German time) and let it run quite some time, now it worked instantly!

Comment: so issue solved I guess, thanks for your help anways!!

Comment: If it is of any help, I also faced this issue today and I solved it by killing the emulator and re-running `react-native run-ios`, which in turned recompiled everything. It's probably obvious, but I'm new to react native and somehow thought that `npm run start` takes care of that as well.

Comment: @Ari ok, it happens again! I'm setting up another realm react native project right now, but `rnpm link realm` stalls again... maybe it's related to `rnpm` not `realm` itself?

Comment: @nburk there were issues with some versions of `rnpm`. Make sure you are updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently an issue causing the postlink script to not get run properly. Running the command manually should resolve the issue until we have a more permanent solution:

```
node node_modules/realm/scripts/rnpm-postlink.js
```

Comment: This should be resolved with the latest version of rnpm